# Is it possible to access the same Ehcache object from two different java applications?

Tags: java, weblogic, ehcache

I have two Java applications.

One is a jar file that executes and writes certain data to the EhCache.

The another application is installed as a war on weblogic server.

My question is that is there any way to access the same Ehcache object that was written by the jar file from the war application and retrieve the data from it?

The weblogic and the jar file are on the same machine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is : Yes, possible but not straightforward, you will need some work.

What you are looking for in your case is cache replication, [check out details here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/replication)

If both the applications one in your JAR file and the one in WAR file are running constantly and synchronously (i.e. only one of them will **NOT** be down at any given point) then RMI can be your choice. If one of application is expected to be down while other is up, then you will need to hold the cache object/data somewhere and JMS is one of natural choices. If they are on same machine or not does not really matter.

What you are basically wanting to do is JVM to JVM communication - and it can be for any object not necessarily for Ehcache. Some of other options are discussed [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/567846/java/java/JVM-JVM-Communication)

Understand that the "Objects" in a JVM are temporary and will die when they are no longer referenced or when JVM dies. Anytime you want them to be transported outside JVM, you will need to write in some hard medium like File, A message or transport them over mechanisms like RMI or a service call. While transporting there, you will need to convert the object in a language which the target understands - which is basically marshalling and un-marshalling or serialization and de-serialization.

Comment: Welcome. You can upvote/mark it as right answer if it useful.